# Loop to fill a data entry - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, automated-tests

How to make a loop to scan a matrix and bring the data from it one by one and fill in the entry ?

The image illustrates the problem ... I need to spend several times by the method and get the data from it and fill in the entry and follow the automation of the normal flow .

I can fill in data entry method :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[1]")).sendKeys(offers());
```

I click filter the data to populate it TextArea :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[2]")).click();
```

Select the populated data in textArea :

```
Select selecionapermanenciamulta = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/select")));
        selecionapermanenciamulta.selectByIndex(0);
```

I click the arrow to take him to the other side :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]")).click();
```

[image: loop]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you can just put that code in a for loop to accomplish what you want. `for (int i = 0; i < numOfTimesToLoop; i++) { }`

Comment: @Andrio You can show me how it would be in my code , please? I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

So to have it loop the actions you listed, you can use a for loop, like this:

```
    int numOfTimesToLoop = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfTimesToLoop; i++) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[1]")).sendKeys(offers());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[2]")).click();

        Select selecionapermanenciamulta = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/select")));
        selecionapermanenciamulta.selectByIndex(0);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]")).click();
    }
```

That, for example, will loop it 5 times. For this kind of loop you'll need to know how many times you need to loop it.

Alternatively, you can use a while loop to loop until some condition is met:

```
while (someConditionNotYetMet) {
    //all those webdriver actions
}
```

Comment: It did not work , it does the following passage , emits the error

 Unable to locate element : 'driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[1]")).sendKeys(offers());'

Comment: @PauloSilva that was the code you provided. If it couldn't be found, something must be wrong with that xpath selector.

Comment: I was not understanding why he does not find the dial at the time of iteration, because the first pass he finds usually put the ID and the name and the error happens exatamento at the time of repeating the operation.